# AWS web socket api won't respond to action

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, wscat

This code should respond to allowAccess and declineAccess events by sending connectionId and message to the user who sent the request(CLI).

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const ENDPOINT = '0ai42l08l3.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/production/';

const client = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({
    endpoint: ENDPOINT
});

async function sendToRequestor(id, message) {
    try {
        await client.postToConnection({
            'ConnectionId': id,
            'Data': Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(message))
        });
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    const connectionId = event.requestContext.connectionId;
    const route = event.requestContext.routeKey;
    
    switch(route) {
        case '$default':
            break;
        case '$connect':
            break;
        case '$disconnect':
            break;
        case 'createRoom':
            break;
        case 'allowAccess':
            await sendToRequestor(connectionId, 'accessAllowed');
            break;
        case 'declineAccess':
            await sendToRequestor(connectionId, 'accessDeclined');
            break;
        default:
            console.log('Unknown route');
            break;
    }
    
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(event),
    };
    return response;
};
```

But when I send { "action": "allowAccess" } or { "action": "declineAccess" } using wscat I don't get any response from the server